# Switching to Release Mode in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I have an Android Firemonkey app and I want to release it. 
But I can't switch to the release mode and the program runs in debug mode. 
I tried these : 
Changing configuration in Project Options (Top toolbar). 
Using Shift + Ctrl + F9 instead of F9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Open the *Project Manager*. From the menu with *View* | *Project Manager*, or using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>.
- In the project tree view find the *Build Configurations* node.
- Open that node and double click *Release*.

Alternatively the Project Manager has a toolbar with a button giving control over the active configuration:

[image]

---

As for what you were doing, the drop down in the project options dialog determines which configuration's settings are being modified rather than which configuration is active. The <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> shortcut is for *Run without debugging*. That determines how the process is started (without attaching a debugger) rather than how it is built.